# Surjection allowing a countable set to imply another countable set.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

So, I have two sets A and B and there is a surjection from A to B. Given this surjection, I have to show that

A is countable implies B is countable.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $A$ is countable by definition means that either there is an injection from $A$ into $\mathbb{N}$ or there is a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $A$. Assume there is a surjection $g$ from $\mathbb{N}$ onto $A$. Then compose the surjection $g$ with the surjection $f$ from $A$ to $B$ to get a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $B$. Can you see why this would imply that $B$ is countable?

Also note that the main set-theoretic argument you need to invoke here is that the composition of surjective functions is again surjective, try and prove this if you're not familiar witht his result.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is countable, we can write $A$ as a sequence $a_1,a_2,\dots$ Consider the sequence $f(a_1),f(a_2),\dots$ where $f$ is the surjection. This sequence contains all of $B$ but there may be repeats. Define a new sequence $b_n$ which starts with $b_1=f(a_1)$ but skips $f(a_i)$ whenever $f(a_i)$ was already included in $b_1,\dots,b_{i-1}$. The sequence $b_n$ now contains all of $B$ without repeats. Hence, $B$ can be enumerated as a sequence and is countable.

Comment: Okay I understand this, thank you very much! How about the negation (kind of). There is an injection from A to B how does A being uncountable show B is also uncountable?

Comment: Do a similar thing. If $B$ was countable, it could be enumerated as a sequence say $b_n$. Now consider the sequence $a_n$ which starts with $a_1=f^{-1}(b_1)$, if it exists. Basically, make a sequence of inverses under $f$ and skip all elements without inverses. Since $f$ is injective, inverses are unique and so there are no repeats in the new sequence. The new sequence is an enumeration of $A$ contradicting that $A$ is uncountable.

Comment: Once you know that each element of B is contained in a sequence, you know it’s countable, so you don’t have to consider the repeats.